# How to increase the number of lines around binding.pry?

Tags: ruby, debugging, pry, byebug

Using the gem `pry-byebug`, when I add a `binding.pry` somewhere, it shows only 5 lines around the line that I am:

```
    157:       max_bytes: limits_config.max_read_bytes_per_parser,
    158:       max_reads: limits_config.max_reads_per_parser,
    159:       max_seeks: limits_config.max_seeks_per_parser
    160:     )
    161:
 => 162:     results = parsers.lazy.map do |parser|
    163:       # Reset all the read limits, per parser
    164:       limited_io.reset_limits!
    165:       read_limiter_under_cache.reset_limits!
    166:
    167:       # We need to rewind for each parser, anew
```

Is there a way to increase this number to show more lines of code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`whereami`](https://github.com/pry/pry/blob/c123bce66116c2bb050ad47d0006e9df215ff3be/lib/pry/commands/whereami.rb) with an integer argument specifying the number of lines to return.

For example, given the file `foo.rb`:

```rb
# foo.rb

require 'pry'

def foo; end

def bar; end

def foobar
  # do something
  binding.pry
  # do something else
end

def baz; end

def foobarbaz; end

foobar
```

Run it with `ruby foo.rb`:

```
From: /Users/foo/foo.rb:11 Object#foobar:

     9: def foobar
    10:   # do something
 => 11:   binding.pry
    12:   # do something else
    13: end

⇒
```

And ask to see +/- 10 lines with `whereami 10`:

```
⇒ whereami 10

From: /Users/foo/foo.rb:11 Object#foobar:

     1: # foo.rb
     2:
     3: require 'pry'
     4:
     5: def foo; end
     6:
     7: def bar; end
     8:
     9: def foobar
    10:   # do something
 => 11:   binding.pry
    12:   # do something else
    13: end
    14:
    15: def baz; end
    16:
    17: def foobarbaz; end
    18:
    19: foobar

⇒
```

Or just the two surrounding lines with `whereami 1`:

```
⇒ whereami 1

From: /Users/foo/foo.rb:11 Object#foobar:

    10:   # do something
 => 11:   binding.pry
    12:   # do something else

⇒
```